# CSS3 transform - rotate and font goes away

Tags: css, fonts, rotation, transform

I'm using this simple css3 transformation rule on an html element (wich contains many other elements like h1,h2,inputs,and img):

```
    div{ 
  -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(-3deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(-3deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    -o-transform: scale(1) rotate(-3deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotate(-3deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotate(-3deg) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) skewX(0deg) skewY(0deg); 

 }
```

the problem is font is skretched as you can see how  is this possible?

check img:
[image]

Is there any way/trick to fix font to not skrech or going so bad, when using rotate css3?

**NB**: to avoid comments like "it looks good to me" :D please check deeply word's chars are not vertically well aligned, check for example the word **Quale** the **l** and **e** chars

in Chrome i have no problems, only Firefox seems to make problems with fonts in rotating :(

> As i can see the font is ok only if is a big size font, i mean,
>   font-size:30px and more, if i go under 30px the font is not ok.

Comment: Looks good to me. What would be the expected output?

Comment: @LinusCaldwell eheh you have to look at that deeply :D check deeply chars are not well vertically aligned  in phrase :( , watch for example at **l** and **e** in **Quale** word

Comment: +1 let us know if you find a solution. I'm very interested in this topic too.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell sure really hope to find somenthing that fixs too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read two days ago that different Chrome browsers might render differently CSS3 rotation with and without `-webkit-`.

**UPDATE:**

I have this problem in Chrome also. Rendered output is crispy and unaligned (like in your picture). So i've just tried to apply (in Chrome) `-webkit-filter: opacity(0.999);` or `-webkit-filter: blur(0px);` and it font is not so crispy, it's fine rendered and aligned, but is blured a bit in both cases. Strange. And I think this works with any filter.

In case of Firefox, `-moz-filter` doesn't work so I've found this solution which give same result as `-webkit-filter` in Chrome:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

Numers in `values` are matrix

```
1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0
```

And here is screenshot in FF after rotation and after use filters.

[image]

Fullscreen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vgXB.jpg

And here is [LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NKgHW/) (for Chrome and FF)

Comment: i've tryed the code i updated in question, and Chrome works perfectly really, problem persist in FF :(

Comment: Mhm, I thought WebKit browsers will do nothing without the vendor prefix on `transforms`.

Comment: hey dudes i updated question you can see i putted all the webkit and ms and o and moz prefixes ;) the problem is just on moz as i can see :(

Comment: @okok, does not matter in that case, but Firefox actually uses the styles without vendor prefixed: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: @LinusCaldwell, I've used Firefox, so I didn't know that CSS3 transforms can't work in Chrome without vendor prefixes :)

Comment: @MiljanPuzović i upvoted and i'm still waiting only for someother people to post some other trick if they has, if not i'll check your answer, since it has a value added

Comment: @okok, I reeeeally hope so that someone will bring better solution. This rendering issue drive me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

It can change depending on your internet browser. In my experience, Firefox handles rotation the best. Chrome messes up text, and IE has tons of errors.

You could try rotating with Javascript, but that's a little more complicated than CSS transform. https://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

Comment: if i'll not find any trick in css sure i'll look for js thanks a lot

Comment: Didn't even know there is such a thing. But, if I understand it correctly: This uses a `canvas`. Can an `<input/>` field go inside a `canvas`?

Comment: sure! i'll try i think , first i would like to understand if is possible to avoid js ;)

Answer (score 1):

:-) I see, you're right. Well, I would say, that's just a rendering issue. I guess from 3 different browsers you get 4 different outputs (like usual with transforms). ;-)

Only solution that sometimes works is forcing 3d mode:

```
input{ transform:rotate(-3deg), translate3d(0, 0, 0); }
```

But maybe it does nothing here.

Comment: yep, indeed i tryed **translate3d(0, 0, 0);** just now, it doesn't fix :( , thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @okok, I'm feeling with you. I hate how browsers render transforms differently especially if it comes to 3d and hardware acceleration. It's a mess! Good luck for you!

Comment: yep it's bad, cause i maybe could leave the bug cause people takes about 5min to find the problem in font , but damn, i would like to fix it :P. Thanks to you dude!

Comment: @okok, I have this problem in Chrome also. Rendered output is crispy and unligned (like in your picture). So i've just tried to apply (in Chrome) `-webkit-filter: opacity(0.999);` or `-webkit-filter: blur(0px);` and it font is not so crispy, it's fine rendered and aligned, but is blured a bit in both cases. Strange. P.S. I think this works with any filter.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović understood, well it's a hell, me on Chrome it's ok but not in FF :(

Comment: @okok, try this CSS property in FF, works same like webkit filters in chrome, and rendering is same - no crispy font, but blured a bit. Yes, looks weird, but works :) `filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale")`

Comment: @MiljanPuzović hey that is a niiiice trick, it looks little bit better :P

Comment: @okok, a little bit?! Looks much better to me :P http://i.imgur.com/tUAd1B2.jpg Anyway, I'll update my answer, I like this. I've avoided to use transform just because of this crispy thing, and I like this solution.

Comment: @okok, yes I am :D Blured but nice rendered is still better than crispy and unaligned :D

Comment: @MiljanPuzović yep you're right, it's better, is there anyway to make it less blurred? :D

Comment: @MiljanPuzović yep, this is really frustrating damn :/ thanks dude really appriciated your help!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating a parent div to the input and rotating that instead of rotating the input?